# Entity Framework - when/why do I need to model a "link" table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I will preface it by saying I'm a database person, moving into .NET, MVC, EF etc. So I fully understand about joins and foreign keys and so on but I am struggling with the EF side.

I worked through a tutorial where we did the following:

- create a Student table (StudentID and personal details), a Course table (CourseID and subject details), and an Enrollment table (EnrollmentID, student and course IDs and the grade given to that student for that class).
- create Models, Controllers and Views for Student and Enrollment entities to allow editing the name of a Student, enrolling a student for a class and giving them a grade, list out all enrollments, etc.

In that tutorial the Enrollments table is (what I know as) a "bridge" table because student to class is a many-to-many relationship.

So do I only need this "intermediate" model/view/controller if it's a many-to-many scenario like this?

The actual structure I want to program is:

- Article (ArticleID, title, author, summary, content...) is a member of a
- Category (CategoryID, title, description, ...)

Then I want to have a drop down list (or whatever UI element) of Categories of which clicking on the selected Category will give a page with a table of Title/Author/Summary of the articles that go in that category.

If an Article can be in more than one category ("Effective Use of Catnip" could be under both "Playing Games with Cats" and "Life Hacks") is that where I would need a 'bridge' table?

Please can someone explain in simple terms - whether I am just being put off by the "many to many" nature of the data in that tutorial, or if the 'bridge' table structure is more fundamental to EF for navigating a PK/FK relationship.

Comment: The link table is needed only for `many-to-many` relationship. `one-to-many` is modeled as usual in db with FK in the `many` table of the relation.

Answer (score 3):

I think the tutorial you are reading is trying to introduce you to the basic concepts of EF. If you have a many-to-many relationship, on database side you will always have three tables:

```
Student
Course
Enrollment (Student_Id, Course_Id)
```

On EF world, you can represent those three tables as three different entities. However, if you want to have a more "natural" way of representing the relation between Students and Courses, EF allows you to declare many-to-many as two lists:

```
public class Student {
  ... properties
  virtual List<Course> Courses;
}

public class Course {
 ... properties
 virtual List<Student> Students;
}
```

However, you need to instruct EF how this references on both side needs to be treated. For that, you can use *fluent API*. With this fluent API you can define the table name that references both tables/entities:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasMany<Course>(s => s.Courses)
                .WithMany(c => c.Students)
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("StudentRefId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("CourseRefId");
                            cs.ToTable("StudentCourse");
                        });

}
```

[Check this article](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) explaining the M:N relationship using fluent library API. Is really simple, and with that you don't need this additional element on the middle.

In terms of UI, you just need to select the list of courses the student want to take, or the list of students the course has to have. Is up to you how you want to present the information to the user, as both functionalities (students taking courses and courses defining its students) point to the same m:n relation.

I think a simple way can be to show a `</select>` list with the students, and then show the list of courses he can apply to.

The project you want to create uses the same ideas. Basically, with EF you will always need to think in terms of "tables". It is true that EF allows you to abstract your tables to entities, but still you need to follow some rules. To sum up: you are right. The "bridge" table is where you need to store the many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Also, does OP intend to use CODE FIRST or DB first. Because this apply to CODE FIRST approach but...